# Consulta SQL con mariadb en la cual se mostraran las 3 primeras filas y la ultima fila añadida con su posición para hacer una clasificación

Tags: sql, mariadb

Estoy haciendo una clasificación para un juego, para hacer la clasificación estoy utilizando la siguiente consulta con *MariaDB 10.1.21*:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 'posicion',
       nombre, 
       dificultad as fallos,
       palabra,
       fecha,
       id 
FROM palabras p , 
(SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
where nombre IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY dificultad, fecha DESC LIMIT 3
```

Esta consulta te ordena los registros por dificultad y fecha, también te da la posición en el *ranking* pero resulta que si el jugador no queda entre los tres primeros su posición no se muestra, como es normal.

Busco una consulta que me devuelva los 3 primeros y el último insertado con su posición, el `id` de la última fila insertada lo tengo guardado en *php* en la variable $ultimo

ejemplo:

```
posición nombre dificultad palabra    fecha      id

1          pepe     0      morsa      2018-01-04 1
2          pepe     1      hola       2018-12-30 2
3          pepe     4      niño       2018-12-31 3
7          pablo    7      paragüero  2019-01-04 4
```

Pablo sería el último jugador como falló 7 veces quedaría por debajo de los 3 primeros y me gustaría que lo mostrara con su posición

Comment: Podes mostrar los datos de entrada?

Comment: A que te refieres con los datos de entrada? los datos guardados en la base de datos son: nombre del jugador(varchar), dificultad(entero del 1 al 8), fecha de la partida, id (int identificador de fila). Estos son los datos mas relevantes

Comment: Esas son las columnas. Los datos son la informacion contenida en las mismas. Cuando pedis que te ayudemos con un query, necesitamos datos para probar que puede estar fallando o faltando. Tenes que mostrar algunos datos de entrada, y como seria la salida con esos datos.

Comment: ejemplo de datos de entrada:
nombre: pepe,
dificultad: 6,
palabra:morsa,
fecha: 2019-01-04 14:59:35,
id:23

Comment: edita la pregunta. toda la info debe estar ahi...

Comment: ¿Qué versión de MariaDB está usando?.

Comment: version 10.1.21-MariaDB

Comment: @javier **[edit] la pregunta** con la información solicitada - Los comentarios son temporales.

Comment: ¿Qué cantidad de registros/filas/tuplas se estima para la tabla `palabras` (millones, más...)?, aquí una opción que le puede dar ideas [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ef4459bd97ee27b4ba03be27c028b5a0), pero debe evaluar posibles problemas de desempeño/performance de la consulta.

Comment: Gracias por responder @wchiquito La consulta devuelve en vez de la ultima inserción otro valor de otra fila que no es la ultima que se ha insertado (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5cfb81c7410e77eb37ca403882c5221e )

Comment: ¿El último insertado sin importar los criterios de ordenación ya establecidos, es decir, un MAX(`\`id\``)?.

Comment: si, que me devolviera el ultimo insertado y la posición que le corresponde al ultimo insertado segun la base de datos, supongo que se puede utilizar max (`id`)

Comment: Aquí la consulta modificada [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5789a9a37ad6088677417c5163b031a4).

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave: en su [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/227239/consulta-sql-con-mariadb-en-la-cual-se-mostraran-las-3-primeras-filas-y-la-ultim#comment422123_227239), cuando dice: "_Los comentarios son temporales_", ¿qué significa "_temporales_"?, es decir, ¿pasado cierto tiempo se eliminan automáticamente los comentarios de las preguntas o respuetas?.

Comment: @wchiquito es correcto, los comentarios son eliminados *(ya sea porque son reportados para eliminación y/u otras circunstancias similares)*.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave: Ok, perfecto, pero no es un proceso automático, es decir, debe existir una circunstancia para que se decida eliminarlos o borrarlos, en caso contrario, permanecen sin alteración.

Comment: @wchiquito al redactar un comentario usted puede ver un texto así: `Utiliza los comentarios para pedir más información o para sugerir mejoras. Evita los comentarios como “+1” o “gracias”`. Los comentarios *[al ser temporales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)* no son un espacio para colocar información valiosa que debe ir en la pregunta. Esta es una de las razones por las que la comunidad pide a los usuarios [edit] la pregunta para agregar información relevante a la misma. También le sugiero leer esta [respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/271772). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que se me ocurre es trabajar con una tabla temporal, para persistir en primer lugar la posición:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T AS (
    SELECT  @rownum := @rownum + 1 'posicion',
            nombre, 
            dificultad as fallos,
            palabra,
            fecha,
            id 
            FROM palabras p,
            (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
            where nombre IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY dificultad, fecha DESC 
);
```

Y ahora si, teniendo la posición, podemos hacer la consulta que buscas:

- Los tres primeros
- El último insertado

Y ahora sí la consulta final:

```
SELECT  *
        FROM T
        WHERE posicion <= 3
              OR id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM T)
        ORDER BY posicion
```

Comment: En principio mi idea era, igualmente, usar Common Table Expression (CTE) y Window Functions, por ello mi pregunta sobre la versión de MariaDB usada, pero al ser 10.1.21, dichas funcionalidades no están disponibles.

Comment: @wchiquito, tienes razón, fue la dislexia, disponible desde la 10.2.1 no 10.1.21

Comment: Gracias por responder @Patricio Moracho no busco la ultima posición del ranking busco el ultimo id insertado, supongo que tu consulta se podria variar cambiando MAX (posicion) por MAX(id)

Comment: @javier, absolutamente, ahora la modifico

Comment: @PatricioMoracho un problema es que no se puede hacer mas de una referencia al a tabla temporal en la misma consulta por lo que se debe sustituir `SELECT MAX(id) FROM T` por el valor del último insertado obtenido de otra consulta

Answer (score 1):

Una solucion rapida podria ser que uses un UNION para unir las dos consultas, la que ya tienes que te muestra los 3 primeros y una nueva que te muestre solamente el ultimo registro insertado. algo asi:

```
(SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 'posicion',
   nombre, 
   dificultad as fallos,
   palabra,
   fecha,
   id 
 FROM palabras p , 
 (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
 where nombre IS NOT NULL 
 ORDER BY dificultad, fecha DESC LIMIT 3 ) 
UNION 
(SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 'posicion',
   nombre, 
   dificultad as fallos,
   palabra,
   fecha,
   id 
 FROM palabras order by id desc limit 1)
```

Tal vez tengas que modificar la segunda query a tu necesidad.

Comment: seguro que tu primer consulta devuelve los 3 primeros?, checa bien como funciona `DESC`

Comment: DESC solo se aplica a fecha, los fallos quiero que los ordene ascendentemente de modo que quien tenga 0 fallos este antes que el que tenga 1.

La respuesta que me propones @Jhon Arteaga tiene un inconveniente que:
La posición que recibe el jugador que ha jugado por ultima vez  siempre es la 4 no recibe su posición en relación con las otras personas almacenadas en la base de datos